# Android activity scene transition different animation target

Tags: android, android-animation

Consider this use case: The home screen has two buttons, when the user clicks the "Generate Random Number" button, a random number is generated and use a full screen activity to display the number. The generated random number is shown after "Last Number Generated:" afterwards. I am trying to use `ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation()` to add activity transition animation. So when the user clicks on the "Generate Random Number" button the full screen activity expands from it. But when the user dismisses the full screen activity I want to use the "Last Number Generated:" as the animation target. However I find no way to do that with ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(). When the full screen activity dismisses the animation target will always be the original view that starts the animation. Is there any trick to achieve behavior? Here is the source code:

MainActivity.kt:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        findViewById<TextView>(R.id.generate).setOnClickListener {
            startActivity(Intent(this, FullScreenActivity::class.java).apply {
                val randomNum = Random().nextInt(100)
                putExtra(FullScreenActivity.KEY, randomNum)
                findViewById<TextView>(R.id.last_result).text = "Last Number Generated: $randomNum"
            }, ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(
                this, findViewById<TextView>(R.id.generate), "random"
            ).toBundle())
        }
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/last_result"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="18dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:transitionName="random"
        android:text="Last Number Generated:"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/generate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="18dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:text="Generate Random Number"
        android:transitionName="random"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/last_result"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

FullScreenActivity.kt:

```
class FullScreenActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    companion object {
        const val KEY = "KEY"
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_full_screen)
        val randomNumber = intent.getIntExtra(KEY, 0)
        findViewById<TextView>(R.id.full_screen).text = randomNumber.toString()
    }
}
```

activity_full_screen.xml:

```
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/full_screen"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textSize="72sp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:transitionName="random"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"/>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add both `R.id.generate` and `R.id.last_result` in `makeSceneTransitionAnimation` as `sharedElements` with different `transitionName`s.

```
        Pair<View, String> pair1 = new Pair<>(generate, "random");
        Pair<View, String> pair2 = new Pair<>(lastResult, "lastResult");
        Bundle bundle = ActivityOptionsCompat.
                          makeSceneTransitionAnimation(MainActivity.this, pair1, pair2)
                         .toBundle();
        startActivity(intent, bundle);
```

Then in `FullScreenActivity` you should just change somewhere `transitionName` of `R.id.full_screen` from `"random"` to `"lastResult"` (same as `transitionName` of `R.id.last_result` ). I do it in `onBackPressed` method:

```
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        textView.setTransitionName("lastResult");
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

Result:

[image]